# Find the area of the entire region that lies between $r=1+\sin\theta; r=1+\cos\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I have to find the area of the region that lies between the curves $r=1+\sin\theta; r=1+\cos\theta$ . The answer the book gave was 
$\frac {3\pi}{2}-2\sqrt{2}$ . 
I tried generating the curve for $r=1+\cos\theta$ from $\frac {\pi}{4}$ to $\pi$, which generated the proper part of the curve, and then generating the curve for $r=1+\sin\theta$ from $\frac {-3\pi}{4}$ to $\frac {\pi}{4}$ which generated the correct part of that curve. I then attempted to put that into the formula given for area between polar curves, $A=2(\int_\alpha^\beta \frac {1}{2}f(\theta)^2 d\theta + \int_\gamma^\alpha \frac {1}{2}g(\theta)^2 d\theta)$ and used the bounds I previously used to generate my curve as the bounds on the integrals, respectively. However, I still am unable to get the answer the book gave. I have thought of trying to divide the section into two and find the area of one half and then doubling my result to find the area of the whole, but I am unsure of how to go about that. Does anyone have any suggestions? The point of intersection I found for the curves is $(1+ \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2} , \frac {\pi}{4})$.

Comment: There are 2 distinct regions where these two curves have areas that lie between them. The range you have allowed for the curve $r=1+\cos\theta$ function only includes one of these regions. Have you tried $\frac{\pi}{4}$  to $\frac{5\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 5):

There are *two* distinct regions where your curves overlap. They do overlap for the intervals of $\theta$ that you give, but that gives only the large overlap at the upper right of the origin. You left out the smaller overlap at the lower left of the origin.

[image]

That overlap is covered by $\frac{5\pi}4\le \theta\le \frac{3\pi}2$ for the $r=1+\cos\theta$ curve and by $\pi\le \theta\le \frac{5\pi}4$ for the $r=1+\sin\theta$ curve. To get the correct answer you will need to include that little piece.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did not see that on the graph. I believe that you meant $\pi \le \theta \le \frac {5\pi}{4}$ for the $r=1+\cos\ \theta$ curve. Was the formula I listed above the correct one to use for computing this particular area? A friend suggested modifications may be made but I am not sure which.

Comment: @CarlySawatzki: Thanks for the correction. I need to run now and can't do more checking: perhaps later.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by separating the figure into four symmetrical parts, two corresponding to the curve $r=1+\sin\ \theta$ and one corresponding to the curve $r=1+\cos\ \theta$. This way the intersecting areas in both quadrants one and four were accounted for. Then, I found the points at which the radius (r) of the curve would be zero, focusing only on the curve $r=1+\cos\ \theta$ as well as using the points I found for the points of intersection, which were at $(1+ \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{\pi}{4})$ and $(1- \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{5\pi}{4})$. I used the formula listed above, which was  $A=2(\int_\alpha^\beta \frac {1}{2}f(\theta)^2 d\theta + \int_\gamma^\alpha \frac {1}{2}g(\theta)^2 d\theta)$.
Thus, the setup for the formula is as follows for the curve $r=1+ \cos\ \theta$: 
 $A=2(\int_\pi^\frac {5\pi}{4} \frac {1}{2}(1+ \cos\ \theta)^2 d\theta + \int_\frac {\pi}{4}^\pi \frac {1}{2}(1+\cos\ \theta)^2 d\theta)$
I then solved each integral separately and added them together, as follows:
$(-\sqrt{2}+\frac{9\pi}{8}-\frac{7}{4})+(-\sqrt{2}+\frac{3\pi}{8}+\frac{7}{4})=(\frac{3\pi}{2}-2\sqrt{2})$, which was the answer given by the book. Thank you all for your help!

Note: This solution was not tested if you use the halves of the curves generated by the $r=1+\sin\ \theta$ curve. I assume it would work similarly if you solved for the values of $\theta$ that would make $\sin\ \theta=-1$ true and used this in your bound for the integral.

Comment: Thanks for leaving the comment about the procedure. I was stuck on the same problem and this was of an immense help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply take an integral for the upper half of the region which is bounded by $r_2=1+\cos\theta$ with $\dfrac{\pi}{4}<\theta<5\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Due to symmetry about $ \theta = \pi/4$ line,

$$ 2\cdot \int_{-3\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac12 (1+\cos(\theta))^2 d \theta  $$

Comment: lower bound is -3pi/4

Comment: Phew! thanks,  corrected typo after your comment.